# Search in Asp.Net Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Filtering by category the pages are displaying correctly. Search from a search box just give results on the first page and it shows the number of pages of the all projects.

My controller below:

```
        public ActionResult Index(string category, string search, int page = 1)
    {
        var viewModel = new ProductsListViewModel();

        var query = repository.Products;


        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(category))
        {
            query = query.Where(p => p.Category == category);
            viewModel.CurrentCategory = category;
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
        {
            query = query.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(search) ||
            p.Details.Contains(search);
            viewModel.Search = search;
        }

        viewModel.Products = query
                        .OrderByDescending(p => p.ProductID)
                        .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
                        .Take(PageSize).ToList();


        viewModel.PagingInfo = new PagingInfo()
        {
            CurrentPage = page,
            ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
            TotalItems = category == null ?
                        repository.Products.Count() :
                        repository.Products.Where(e =>
                            e.Category == category).Count()

        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

my page link for the view:

`<div style="padding-bottom: 10px" page-model="@Model.PagingInfo" page-action="Index" page-classes-enabled="true" page-class="btn" page-class-normal="btn-default" page-class-selected="btn-primary" page-url-category="@Model.CurrentCategory" class="btn-group pull-right">
</div>`

My PagingInfo.cs is:

```
    public int TotalItems { get; set; }
    public int ItemsPerPage { get; set; }
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }

    public int TotalPages =>
        (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)TotalItems / ItemsPerPage);
```

Comment: `.Where(p => p.Description.Contains(search))` ?

Comment: You need to cast your query to Queryable<T> to apply search according to parameters

Comment: @Pawel, how do I write `.Where(p => p.Description.Contains(search))` with `.Where(p => category == null || p.Category == category)` inside the same method?

Comment: @RochaCarter07 check my edit

Comment: @DawoodAwan I see that, it is working fine. the thing is for search funcionality the pages is not showing correctly . I will try to route it.

Comment: @Pawel,  @DawoodAwan, this code seems like it just allow to filter by category. If I search on searchbox the paging does not work well, it just give results on first page   `viewModel.PagingInfo = new PagingInfo()
        {
            CurrentPage = page,
                ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                TotalItems = category == null ?
                            repository.Products.Count() :
                            repository.Products.Where(e =>
                                e.Category == category).Count()

            };`

Comment: You must be doing something wrong. Post your new query etc. In the question. You can edit your question

Comment: @DawoodAwan, see my edit.

Comment: I don&#39;t see you passing the page number in the url i.e page. So page is always 1 maybe. Debug you action.

Comment: @DawoodAwan, how do I do that?

Comment: @Pawel how do you write that?

Answer (score 2):

You could break it up like this:

```
public ActionResult List(string category, string search, int page = 1)
{
    var model = new ProductsListViewModel();

    var query = repository.Products;


    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(category))
    {
        query = query.Where(p => p.Category == category);
        model.CurrentCategory = category;
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
    {
        query = query.Where(p => p.Description.Contains(search));
        model.Search = search;
    }

    var count = query.Count();

    model.Products = query
                    .OrderByDescending(p => p.ProductID)
                    .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
                    .Take(PageSize).ToList();

    model.PagingInfo = new PagingInfo()
                {
                    CurrentPage = page,
                    ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                    TotalItems = count
                };

    return View(model);
}
```